# Chrome redirection (SP modal newform window)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sharepoint

i'm using JavaScript to make some small customization in default SharePoint 2013 issue tracker. When user submit an issue (default SharePoint function presave) JavaScript should redirect document to new URL. Everything works fine in Firefox in IE but from unknown reason redirection doesn't work in Chrome.

I'm used location, replace.href, assign etc - result the same - chrome just save the form without redirection. Can you give me any hint why it doesn't work?

I'm using SP 2013 online (and i don't have access to SP designer)

```
<script src="/sites/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SiteAssets/Scripts/sessvars.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Here i have small function to get email from sharepoint peoplePicker field
    function getEmailFromPeoplePicker(title) {
        var ppDiv = $("div[title='" + title + "']")[0];
        var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[ppDiv.id];
        var userList = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
        var userInfo = userList[0];
        var userEmail;
        if(userInfo != null)
        {
            userEmail = userInfo.EntityData.Email;
        }
        return userEmail;
    }


    function PreSaveAction(){
        // check if there is attachment
        if ($('#onetidIOFile').get(0).files.length === 0) {
    } else {
    OkAttach()  //attach file to form
    }

    //get email from field
    var RequestApprover = getEmailFromPeoplePicker('Assigned To');
    //create link for redirection with email at the end (ill use it latter for sending emails) 
     var targetUrl = '/sites/SitePages/RedirectDestination.aspx' + '#' + RequestAprover;
     //window.location.href = targetUrl;
    //location.replace(targetUrl);
    //window.location.assign(targetUrl);
   // window.top.location.href = targetUrl;           
   window.location.assign(targetUrl);  // <---------- redirection which works in IE and FireFox but not in Chrome
    //window.location.href = targetUrl;
     //window.location.assign(targetUrl);
     //window.parent.location.href(targetUrl);
     //setTimeout(function(){location.href = targetUrl},500);
    return true;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have "return false;" (instead of return true;) at the end of your PreSaveAction function implementation. Looks like in Chrome redirect takes more time then in other browsers, so Sharepoint continues usual form flow (e.g. continues to PreSaveItem etc.)

Comment: Дякую for your answer :), I've test return false; previously and redirection works as it should - but I need to save my form before redirect the page

Comment: great! I'm glad it helps. please do not forget to mark answer as one that solved your problem (if it helped :) ). good luck.

Comment: It works only partly - now i can redirect but sharepoint form wasn't saved (because i've returned false). I thinking about window.open only for chrome but it is a workaround that i want to avoid.

Comment: got it. In this case, looks like PreSaveAction function is not right place to do this redirect

Comment: look here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191251/how-can-i-redirect-to-google-after-save-button-is-clicked-in-my-list/191252#191252 .You can override onclick of your save button (input[id$=SaveItem]). In general, idea is to path "source" param (equals to your redirect url) to post back url. Then sharepoint will redirect to your page on server side.

Comment: It looks like changing the save button was only reasonable solution. Thank you for your help